# Android AIDL remote Service for 3rd party developers

Tags: android, service, aidl

I am writing a SDK which defines a remote Service and provides a AIDL interface for 3rd party developers. For my testing, I install the SDK as an Android app (XYZService.apk), although its just a background service(which does not start until a Client binds to it) and there are no Activities defined. I also install my test client app as the second app (TestClient.apk). TestClient app has Activities and on launch, it binds to the XYZService and starts it.

But I am confused how should I package this SDK for 3rd party developers. Lets say 3rd party developer writes a new client ClientFoo.apk.  How do they provide XYZService.apk to their users who download ClientFoo.apk via Google Play. Do I have to make XYZService.apk availavle via Goolge Play ? is there any way 3rd party developer can package XYZService along with their .apk file ?

Can I provide a JAR file to 3rd party developers. Basically, providing a JAR for my remote service will be an idea solution for me.

thanks a lot for your answers. I am new to Android development.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to make XYZService.apk availavle via Goolge Play ?

You have to distribute it somehow. APK files do not appear on users' devices by magic. Whether you use Google Play or some other distribution mechanism is up to you.

> is there any way 3rd party developer can package XYZService along with their .apk file ?

Yes, by getting rid of the APK, getting rid of the AIDL, and implementing your SDK as a JAR or Android library project. Distributing reusable code as a JAR has been in use in Java-based development for around 15 years.

You use AIDL and an APK if you are distributing your own app, that the user wants independently of anything else, and that you *additionally* want to allow third parties to access a service exposed by your app. If you do not have such an app, or do not want users to have to install a separate app, you should be giving a JAR or Android library project, so your code is baked into the third parties' apps.

> Can I provide a JAR file to 3rd party developers

You can implement your SDK as a JAR, so long as it does not require resources -- then, you will need to distribute it as an Android library project.